# SharePointOnline Bulk UPS update job stuck on Queued

Tags: sharepoint-online, ups

I am trying to run a bulk update of UPS in SharePointOnline. I had a few successful runs. But now the latest job I am running has been stuck in a Queued state for over 12 hours. Any idea?

I am using the process described here -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online

However the status is showing as follows-

```
Request status: Queued - Error status: NoError
```

Any idea how I can cancel or restart?

Comment: It seems there is a DeleteImportProfilePropertiesJob method. Anyone know how to use it?   
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt643032%28v%3doffice.15%29

Comment: Just an update....the jobs eventually completed with errors...but it was Queued for several days which seemed odd. So am able to proceed now.